# Dynamically reading all data catalog tables with AWS Glue Job

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, aws-glue

So I managed to create a AWS Glue Crawler that crawls all my tables and stores them in a data Catalog tables. My database has around 25 tables and I can see them.

I also managed to create an Glue job that copys one table to a bucket and saves it as a .csv file. Which works quite nicely and looks like this:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)


# Script generated for node Postgres
Postgres_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="glue_database",
    table_name="sensors",
    transformation_ctx="Postgres_node1",
)

Postgres_node1 = Postgres_node1.repartition(1)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=Postgres_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("placeholder_data", "int", "placeholder_data", "int"),
        ("end_at", "timestamp", "end_at", "timestamp"),
        ("deleted", "boolean", "deleted", "boolean"),
        ("placeholder_data", "boolean", "placeholder_data", "boolean"),
        ("placeholder_data", "int", "placeholder_data", "int"),
        ("start_at", "timestamp", "placeholder_data", "timestamp"),
        ("placeholder_data", "int", "placeholder_data", "int"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Get the current date as a string
current_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "path": f"s3://bucketname/postgres/{current_date}",  
        "mode": "append", 
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

But this is just for one table, and in the glue visual editor I cant seem to find an "all tables option". Is there a way I can dynamically read all tables and execute the above generated code so that it generates 25 .csv's for me? Of course I would need to edit the mapping but I assume I can also get that from the table. But i'm currently stuck on trying to import the data catalog and reading all the tables from it.

My end goal is querying and visualising the data with Quicksight and Athena by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `boto3` client in your Glue script. Using the visual studio won't work for this use case. So you will need to switch your job to be a script-based one.

Here is some code to loop through your tables in a glue catalog, and then write a DataFrame per one.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('glue')

def get_glue_tables(database=None):
    next_token = ''
    tables = []
    
    while True:
        response = client.get_tables(
            DatabaseName=database,
            NextToken=next_token
        )
        
        for table in response.get('TableList'):
            tables.append(table.get('Name'))
            
        next_token = response.get('NextToken')
        
        if next_token is None:
            return tables
```

By doing this though, you will need to have to apply your mappings to each table. So it would make more sense to have a job per table if you need to perform different mappings on each one. But if that's not a problem, you could use this function to loop through and write each one as a DataFrame like so:

```
for table in get_glue_tables(db_name):
    DataCatalogtable_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database=db_name,
        table_name=table,
        transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node1",
    )
    
    s3_path = f"s3://bucketname/postgres/{current_date}",
    S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
        connection_type="s3",
        format="csv",
        connection_options={
           "path": f"s3://bucketname/postgres/{current_date}",  
           "mode": "append", 
           "partitionKeys": [],
        },
        transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
    )
```